# Split a dataframe evenly without separating the grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe similar to below:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(4214)

df <- data.frame(value = sample(x = 1:50, 70, replace = TRUE),
                 group = sample(x = letters, 70, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(group)
```

Where `group` is my grouping variable, and each value occurring at different frequencies (e.g. `group == "a"` occurs 5 times, `group == "b"` occurs 6 times, etc).

I need to split this data as evenly as possible into `n = 9` subset dataframes.  However, the catch is that I can't split the same grouping variable between subsets.  For instance, `group == "b"` cannot occur in both subset 1 and subset 2.

```
n <- 9
df %>% 
  mutate(divider = rep(x = 1:n, 
                       each = ceiling(nrow(.)/n), 
                       length.out = nrow(.))) %>%
  split(.$divider)
```

Here I create a `divider` column, in the hopes of splitting the data into subsets.  But a given value for a `group` may have two different values for `divider`.  And so the grouping variables are divided between the subsets here.  I have been trying to improve this with `nest` and `lag`, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I'm aware that the subsets will not have equal row numbers, but I'm hoping for something like the following:

```
$`1`
# A tibble: 11 x 3
  value group divider
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1    43 a           1
2    22 a           1
3     1 a           1
4     5 a           1
5     4 a           1
6    18 b           1
7    32 b           1
8    33 b           1
9    47 b           1
10   43 b           1
11   35 b           1

$`2`
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  value group divider
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1    24 c           2
2     3 d           2
3    12 d           2
4    13 e           2
5     6 e           2
6    45 f           2

$`3`
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, but that depends on the ordering of your data, is to count instances by group and separate them by the closest integer to the number of groups you want.

If you need 9 groups, sum the cumulative frequencies and divide by 9. Take the integer and use it as the new splitting variable for your datasets

```
dftab <- as.data.frame(table(df$group)) %>%
  mutate(nobs = cumsum(Freq),
         newgrouping = ceiling(nobs/9)) %>%
  group_by(newgrouping ) %>%
  summarise(number_obs = sum(Freq))

dftab

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  newgrouping number_obs
        <dbl>      <int>
1           1          5
2           2         12
3           3          9
4           4         10
5           5          9
6           6          7
7           7         11
8           8          7
```

As for the "as evenly as possible" we can run a dumb optimization in the standard deviation from the number of observations across groups. Here, relying on the ordering of the group variable helps in the process.

```
set.seed(4214)

df <- data.frame(value = sample(x = 1:50, 70, replace = TRUE),
                 group = sample(x = letters, 70, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  arrange(group)


store_group <- list()
store_sd <- NA_integer_

for(i in 1:1000){

  dftab <- table(df$group) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>% 

    # important step is to shuffle the group variable every iteration
    mutate(group = factor(Var1, levels = df$group %>%
                            unique %>%
                            sample)) %>%
    arrange(group) %>%

    mutate(nobs = cumsum(Freq),
           newgrouping = ceiling(nobs/9)) %>%

    select(newgrouping, group, Freq)

  store_group[[i]] <- dftab

  df_sd <- dftab %>%
    group_by(newgrouping) %>%
    summarise(number_obs = sum(Freq))

  store_sd[i] <- sd(df_sd$number_obs)
}
```

which results in

```
store_group[[which.min(store_sd)]] %>%
       group_by(newgrouping) %>%
       summarise(number_obs = sum(Freq))

  newgrouping number_obs
        <dbl>      <int>
1           1          9
2           2          9
3           3          9
4           4          8
5           5          9
6           6          9
7           7          8
8           8          9
```

where `store_group[[which.min(store_sd)]]` has the original data with the "best" grouping possible (given the number of iterations in the loop) without having the same `group` across datasets when you split them by `newgrouping` variable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an alphabetical solution as shown in your expected output; you could round the `cumsum`s divided by the desired number of splits (i.e. `9`), which should alter ceiling and floor and distribute groups more evenly. This results in vector `x` with split indicators assigned to each category of your `group` variable. `x` splitted by itself then gives a list with which tha data frame can be split with `lapply`.

```
x <- round(cumsum(table(dat$group)) / (nrow(dat) / 9))
result <- lapply(lapply(split(x, x), names), function(i) dat[dat$group %in% i, ])
```

***Rows distribution in result list***

```
t(Map(nrow, result))
#      1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# [1,] 11 6 9 8 7 7 8 7 7

> sapply(result, "[", 2)
$`1.group`
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"

$`2.group`
[1] "c" "d" "d" "e" "e" "f"

$`3.group`
[1] "g" "g" "g" "g" "i" "j" "j" "j" "j"

$`4.group`
[1] "k" "k" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l" "l"

$`5.group`
[1] "n" "n" "o" "p" "p" "p" "p"

$`6.group`
[1] "q" "q" "q" "q" "r" "r" "r"

$`7.group`
[1] "s" "s" "s" "t" "u" "u" "u" "v"

$`8.group`
[1] "w" "w" "w" "x" "x" "x" "x"

$`9.group`
[1] "y" "y" "y" "y" "z" "z" "z"
```

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(value = c(43L, 22L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 18L, 32L, 33L, 
47L, 43L, 35L, 24L, 3L, 12L, 13L, 6L, 45L, 12L, 5L, 22L, 47L, 
35L, 20L, 36L, 34L, 15L, 22L, 9L, 41L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 21L, 3L, 8L, 
33L, 12L, 39L, 19L, 2L, 34L, 45L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 20L, 19L, 
45L, 36L, 25L, 23L, 47L, 13L, 45L, 36L, 23L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 
11L, 25L, 31L, 41L, 14L, 38L, 15L, 13L, 6L), group = c("a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", 
"e", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "i", "j", "j", "j", "j", "k", "k", 
"l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "n", "n", "o", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
"q", "q", "q", "q", "r", "r", "r", "s", "s", "s", "t", "u", "u", 
"u", "v", "w", "w", "w", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"z", "z", "z")), row.names = c(6L, 21L, 50L, 66L, 69L, 15L, 36L, 
46L, 48L, 62L, 67L, 34L, 18L, 54L, 31L, 51L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 24L, 
39L, 55L, 8L, 11L, 27L, 29L, 59L, 70L, 19L, 23L, 40L, 45L, 52L, 
68L, 26L, 43L, 44L, 16L, 38L, 63L, 65L, 10L, 49L, 56L, 61L, 1L, 
13L, 64L, 22L, 35L, 47L, 4L, 25L, 33L, 53L, 37L, 14L, 17L, 60L, 
2L, 5L, 12L, 57L, 28L, 32L, 41L, 42L, 20L, 30L, 58L), class = "data.frame")
```